# Search query using two parameters or more in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm still new at the Hibernate/JPA world and i'm stuck here trying to make a function in the same way of searching by id but i'm trying to search and return fields from the database using two parameters, i did a DAO method to my project too with the basic CRUD operations plus this special one. At the time to do the search it gave me this return stacktrace:

```js
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.exemplo.model.Pedido. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.sql.Date
 at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1135)
 at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1068)
 at com.exemplo.repositorio.MySQLPedidoDAO.pesquisarPorData(MySQLPedidoDAO.java:82)
 at com.exemplo.view.ViewPedidos.btBuscarActionPerformed(ViewPedidos.java:322)
 at com.exemplo.view.ViewPedidos.access$000(ViewPedidos.java:23)
 at com.exemplo.view.ViewPedidos$1.actionPerformed(ViewPedidos.java:106)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
 at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
 at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
 at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
 at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.exemplo.model.Pedido. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.sql.Date
 at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:133)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1066)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2000(SessionImpl.java:176)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2540)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:951)
 at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1110)
 ... 41 more
```

My methods are in this way, DAO class:

```js
public interface DAO <T, K> {

    public void inserir(T o);
    
    public void alterar(T o);

    public void excluir(T o);

    public T pesquisar(K id);

    public List<T> listar();
    
}
```

PedidoDAO:

```js
public interface PedidoDAO extends DAO <Pedido, Long> {
    
    public Pedido pesquisarPorData(Date dataCadastro);
    
}
```

MySQLPedidoDAO: (Error at PesquisarPorData function)

```js
public class MySQLPedidoDAO implements PedidoDAO {

    public ConnectionFactory cf = null;

    public MySQLPedidoDAO(ConnectionFactory cf) {
        this.cf = cf;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Pedido pesquisar(Long id) {
        cf.createEm().getTransaction().begin();
        Pedido pedido = cf.createEm().find(Pedido.class, id);
        cf.createEm().getTransaction().commit();
        //erro ao deletar pois o factory já está fechado
        //emf.close();
        return pedido;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Pedido pesquisarPorData(Date dataCadastro) {
        cf.createEm().getTransaction().begin();
        // ERROR AT THE LINE UNDER!!!!!
        Pedido pedido = cf.createEm().find(Pedido.class, dataCadastro);
        cf.createEm().getTransaction().commit();
        //erro ao deletar pois o factory já está fechado
        //emf.close();
        return pedido;
    }
    
}
```

ViewPedidos:

```js
public class ViewPedidos extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

    private MySQLPedidoDAO mspdao;
    private Pedido ped;
    private boolean editavel;
    
    /* Getters e Setters from editavel and ped  */
    
    private void btPesquisaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        habilitarApenasOSeData();
        limparCampos();
        tfPedido.setEditable(true);
        tfPedido.requestFocus();
        btBuscar.setEnabled(true);
    } 
    
    
    
    private void btBuscarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        ConnectionFactory cf = new ConnectionFactory();
        MySQLPedidoDAO mspdao = new MySQLPedidoDAO(cf);
        Pedido ped = new Pedido();
        
        if(tfPedido.getText().length() == 0  &&  tfDataCad.getText().length() == 0){
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Search not succeed, please fill the fields above", "Search", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        } else {
             ped = mspdao.pesquisar(Long.parseLong(tfPedido.getText()));
             ped = mspdao.pesquisarPorData(new java.sql.Date(((java.util.Date)tfDataCad.getValue()).getTime()));
             setPed(ped);
             setEditable(true);
             carregarCampos();
             habilitarTextFieldEBotoes();
        }
              
    }   
    
    
}
```

I've tested commenting the codes that involve the date fields only letting the id to be searched and it runned very well, i've tried to do a quick fix to search through id and register date doing two different methods as above, i've tried doing a createQuery and nothing went on, I'd like to know where am i doing wrong? or any tips to make a search function in JPA using two or more params?
 (Obs: my code is in portuguese because it's a brazilian project sorry for it or any mistake) and thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `EntityManager#find` requires that you provide the primary key for your entity (which is a `Long`). If you want to query using other fields you need to use `createQuery` instead.

You haven't provided the entity definition in your question. However the query would be something like:

```
TypedQuery<Pedido> query = cf.createEm().createQuery("id = :id and registerDate = :date", Pedido.class);
query.setParameter("date", dataCadastro);
query.setParameter("id", id);
List<Pedido> results = query.getResultList();
```

If you're only expecting a single result you can call `query.getSingleResult()` instead of `getResultList()`. This will throw `NonUniqueResultException` if there is not a single result.

Comment: So, i'm trying to do something like : "select * from order where id = ? and registerDate = '?' "; in JDBC/MySQL i know that it'd be like that... in JPQL i don't know if is it like: cf.createEm().createQuery("select pedido from pedido Pedido where id = ? and registerDate = '?'); i'm trying to make a function to search data through two params that returns a object from the Pedido type

Comment: I've modified my answer to show you how to create the query you're after.

Comment: Hey Alex!! I've tested the code finally it worked now, i didn't knew about the correct use of this method createQuery() and setParameter() thanks a lot for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Caused by: org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.exemplo.model.Pedido. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.sql.Date

Look from the surface of Exception report.this is so clearly that the exception has told you, expected a Long type, but you put a date type instead of Long.

Comment: in this case i believe that searchEm().find() is only to return objects through his primary key... what i'm trying to do is set a function that be possible to do this query like: "select order from order Order where id = ? and registerDate = '?' "; How could i do it in JPA?! Thanks in advance!